# Removing an item from an array when chef-client is executed

Tags: ruby, chef-recipe, recipe

I am using the firewalld cookbook and having difficulty rewriting the provider code to exclude subnets missing from an array. Below is what the current firewalld provider code looks like. Can some assist with this?

```
use_inline_resources

action :add do
e = execute "add port #{new_resource.name} to zone" do
not_if "firewall-cmd #{zone} --query-rich-rule=\"#{rich_rule}\"
command(<<-EOC)
firewall-cmd #{zone} --add-rich-rule="#{rich_rule}"
firewall-cmd --permanent #{zone} --add-rich-rule="#{rich_rule}"
EOC
end
new_resource.updated_by_last_action(e.updated_by_last_action?)
end

action :remove do
e = execute "remove port #{new_resource.name} from zone" do
only_if "firewall-cmd #{zone} --query-rich-rule=\"#{rich_rule}\""
command(<<-EOC)
firewall-cmd #{zone} --remove-rich-rule="#{rich_rule}"
firewall-cmd --permanent #{zone} --remove-rich-rule="#{rich_rule}"
EOC
end
new_resource.updated_by_last_action(e.updated_by_last_action?)
end

def zone
new_resource.zone ? "--zone=#{new_resource.zone}" : ''
end 

def rich_rule
cmd = "rule "
cmd += "family='#{new_resource.family}' " if new_resource.family
cmd += "source address='#{new_resource.source_address}' " if        new_resource.source_address
cmd += "destination address='#{new_resource.destination_address}' " if new_resource.destination_address
cmd += "service name='#{new_resource.service_name}' " if new_resource.service_name
cmd += "port port='#{new_resource.port_number}' protocol='#{new_resource.port_protocol}' " if new_resource.port_number
cmd += "log " if new_resource.log_prefix || new_resource.log_level || new_resource.limit_value
cmd += "prefix='#{new_resource.log_prefix}' " if new_resource.log_prefix
cmd += "level='#{new_resource.log_level}' " if new_resource.log_level
cmd += "limit value='#{new_resource.limit_value}' " if new_resource.limit_value
cmd += new_resource.firewall_action if new_resource.firewall_action
cmd end
```

My recipe currently looks like this

```
node['cookbook']['iptables']['subnets'].each do |firewall|
  firewalld_rich_rule firewall do
     zone firewall["public"]
     family firewall["ipv4"]
     source_address firewall
     firewall_action firewall["accept"]
     action :add
     end
  end
```

My attributes currently look like this

```
default["cookbook"]["iptables"]["subnets"] = ["172.16.2.0/24","192.168.1.1/24","10.10.10.0/24"]
```

The code is currently working as expected. In other words, when i run the cookbook, it populates firewalld with subnets in the attribute array. However when i delete one of the subnets and run the cookbook, it doesn't delete the excluded subnet. Is there a way to write this whereby it automatically deletes any rich rule subnet not in the array?